# Restarting game using storyboard using Corona SDK and getting a weird error

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, uistoryboard

I'm currently making a game in Corona that has three different scenes with a menu, a play, and a end game scene.  In game you move your sprite up and down along the screen when you touch it, and it works fine the first play.  But when you crash into something and go to the restart screen and it loads up the game again, when you touch the screen the sprite barely moves up at all and if you let go it quickly falls to the bottom and you cannot push it back up by touching the screen again.  Any ideas as to why this problem is occurring?

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

-- ================================= --
-- required library files below here --
---------------------------------------
local physics = require("physics");
physics.start(false);
physics.setGravity( 0, 9.8 )

require("mobdebug").start();
---------------------------------------
-- required library files above here --
-- ================================= --


-- ================================ --
-- local vars/references below here --
--------------------------------------

local gameBg;
local cloud;
local cloud2;
local bird;
local crashedBird;
local topBar;
local bottomBar;
local topOfScreen;
local bottomOfScreen;
local group;
_W = display.viewableContentWidth
_H = display.viewableContentHeight


--------------------------------------
-- local vars/references above here --
-- ================================ --


-- =================================== --
-- functions for this scene below here
-----------------------------------------


-----------------------------------------
-- functions for this scene above here
-- =================================== --



------------------
--
--  birdReady
--
------------------
function birdReady()
    bird.bodyType = "dynamic";
end

------------------
--
--  end birdReady
--
------------------

------------------
--
--  activateBird
--
------------------
function activateBird(self,event)
    self:applyForce(0, -0.5, self.x, self.y);
end
------------------
--
--  End activateBird
--
------------------

------------------
--
--  Touch Screen Function
--
------------------
function touchScreen(event)
    if(event.phase == "began") then
        bird.enterFrame = activateBird;
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",bird);
    end

    if(event.phase == "ended") then
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bird);
    end
    return true;
end
-----------------
--
--  TouchScreen End
--
-----------------

-----------------
--
--  gameOver()
--
-----------------
function gameOver()

    bird.collided = false;
    storyboard.gotoScene("menu",  { effect = defaultTransition });
  --physics.setGravity( 0, 9.8 )

end
-----------------
--
--  end gameOver()
--
-----------------


-----------------
--
--  crashed()
--
-----------------
function crashed()
    crashedBird.x = bird.x;
    crashedBird.y = bird.y;
    crashedBird.isVisible = true;
    bird.bodyType = "static";
    bird.isVisible = false;
    gameOver();

end
-----------------
--
--  end crashed()
--
-----------------

-----------------
--
--  onCollision()
--
-----------------
function onCollision(event)
    if(event.phase == "began") then
        if(bird.collided == false) then
            bird.collided = true;
            crashed();
        end
    end
end
-----------------
--
--  end onCollision()
--
-----------------

-----------------
--
--Event Listener for touch
--
-----------------
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen);

-----------------
--
--  End event Listener for touch
--
-----------------

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    group = self.view

    -- CREATE display objects and add them to 'group' here.




    -------------------
    --
    --  Bird
    --
    -------------------
    bird = display.newImage("images/bird.png");
    bird.x = (_W / 2) - 90;
    bird.y = _H / 2;
    bird.xScale = 0.7;
    bird.yScale = 0.8;
    bird.collided = false;


    physics.addBody(bird,"static", {density = 0.1, friction = 0.5, bounce = 0.1, radius = 12});

    group:insert(bird);

    birdIntro = transition.to(bird, {time = 2000, x = 100, onComplete = birdReady});
    --------------------
    --
    -- End Bird
    --
    --------------------

    --------------------
    --
    --  Crashed Bird
    --
    --------------------
    crashedBird = display.newImage("images/crashed.png");
    crashedBird.x = 100;
    crashedBird.y = 100;
    crashedBird.isVisible = false;
    group:insert(crashedBird);
    --------------------
    --
    --  End Crashed Bird
    --
    --------------------



end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    globalGroup = display.newGroup();
    group:insert(globalGroup);


    -- INSERT code here (e.g. start timers, load audio, start listeners, etc.)

    --storyboard.purgeScene("menu");
    --Purge the end game file if added

    storyboard.loadScene("menu");

    --Runtime listener for the touch on the screen
    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen);

    --Moves the cloud from right to left
    cloud.enterFrame = scrollCloud;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cloud);

    --Moves the cloud from right to left
    cloud2.enterFrame = scrollCloud;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cloud2);

    --Moves the top barricade from right to left
    topBar.enterFrame = scrollCloud;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", topBar);

    --Moves the bottom barricade from right to left
    bottomBar.enterFrame = scrollCloud;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", bottomBar);

    --Detects the collision
    Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision);


end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view



  bird:removeSelf();


 gameBg:removeSelf();
 cloud:removeSelf();
 cloud2:removeSelf();

 crashedBird:removeSelf();
 topBar:removeSelf();
 bottomBar:removeSelf();
 topOfScreen:removeSelf();
 bottomOfScreen:removeSelf();
 group:removeSelf();

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)

    Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", touchScreen);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bird);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", cloud);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", cloud2);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", topBar);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bottomBar);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision);
    --storyboard.removeAll ( )

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
  --storyboard.removeAll();
    -- INSERT code here (e.g. remove listeners, widgets, save state, etc.)


  --bird:removeSelf();

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", touchScreen);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bird);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", cloud);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", cloud2);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", topBar);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bottomBar);

    Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision);
  group = nil;
end



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: With something like this you really need to post some code/samples. Otherwise it be will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: @MagicMan I just added in some code samples.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the problem is an issue with you not removing all listeners before exiting to the next scene.  Make sure you clean up all variables and you end all event listeners CORRECTLY.  I am personally not that familiar with storyboard. If you can't get it to work, I would recommend not using anything and just have one main.lua and just require other lua documents by just calling their functions from within main.  Probably will just be alot easier to deal with the error cleanup yourself.